# Filas vacias con OpenXml Excel

Tags: c#, linq, excel

Estoy recorriendo un excel con la librería `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`, y al obtener las filas, obtengo filas en la cual las celdas se encuentran vacías; es decir, tengo un excel donde solo se tiene información en las primeras 10 filas, pero esta extrayendo información de las primeras 140 filas.

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
 {
        IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
        string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadDoc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
        Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
        SheetData underscoreSheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
        IEnumerable<Row> underscoreRows = underscoreSheetData.Elements<Row>();
        var numRows=underscoreRows.Count();
 }
```

Como puedo obtener únicamente las filas en las que hay información, en este caso las 10 primeras filas.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que le falte un `foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())`.

Prueba este ejemplo y si te resulta lo adaptas a tu código:

```
 using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
    string text;
    foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
    {
        foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
        {
            text = c.CellValue.Text;
            Console.Write(text + " ");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tratar filtrandolas mediante Linq este es un ejemplo, de como se podria hacer

```
 sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(row=> 
           row.Elements<Cell>.Any(cell=>   
                !String.IsEmptyOrNull(cell.CellValue.Text)
                                  )).ToList();
```